# Optimize SQL Server Aggregation Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm looking for ideas on how to optimize this query.  I've evaluated the Execution Plan but it does not offer any ideas for a missing index so just curious if writing the query better (different tactics) would result in a faster/lighter query.

```
SELECT [Place], COUNT([Place]) 
FROM (
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(EventPlace1,'T', ''),'*','') [Place] 
        FROM [MS.Prod]..mso_scores UNION
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(EventPlace2,'T', ''),'*','') 
        FROM [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores UNION
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(EventPlace3,'T', ''),'*','') 
        FROM [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores UNION
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(EventPlace4,'T', ''),'*','') 
        FROM [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores UNION
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(EventPlace5,'T', ''),'*','') 
        FROM [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores UNION
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(EventPlace6,'T', ''),'*','') 
        FROM [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores UNION
    SELECT scoresid, REPLACE(REPLACE(AAPlace,'T', ''),'*','') 
        FROM [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores
) data1 
JOIN [MSO.Prod]..mso_scores scores ON scores.scoresid = data1.scoresid
    AND scores.usagnum = '274246' 
    AND scores.TeamResult='N'
WHERE data1.Place IN ('1', '2', '3')
GROUP BY Place
```

So a quick explanation:  there are 6 event place fields.  The data in these fields looks like "1", "2", "1T", "3", "5T"; where "T" is a tie.  I only care about the number, 1,2,3 so am parsing out the "T" or the "*" from the place and then grouping the query for a count.

How many 1st places do they have, how many 2nd places, and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one (for 2008 and higher) -

```
SELECT [Place], COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT [Place] = REPLACE(REPLACE(t.[Place], 'T', ''), '*', '')  
    FROM dbo.mso_scores r
    OUTER APPLY (
        VALUES 
            (EventPlace1),
            (EventPlace2),
            (EventPlace3),
            (EventPlace4),
            (EventPlace5),
            (EventPlace6),
            (AAPlace)
    ) t([Place])
    WHERE r.usagnum = '274246' 
        AND r.TeamResult = 'N'
) d
WHERE d.Place IN ('1', '2', '3')
GROUP BY d.Place
```

For additional information read this topic: [Tips for SQL Query Optimization by Analyzing Query Plan](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/08/28/sql-server-tips-for-sql-query-optimization-by-analyzing-query-plan/)

Comment: So much cleaner then my original code.  Nice.  The execution plan on yours is much simpler where mine is riddled with Nested loops, Compute Scalar, etc.  It still seems a little slow.  I'm going to watch this one and see how it fairs.  If it is too heavy for live data I can always aggregate the data at night.

Comment: Add index on `usagnum`, `TeamResult` columns and add `EventPlace1`, `EventPlace2`, ... , `AAPlace` columns as included to index. And also please specify your server version and `DDL` for your table.

Comment: Please tell, I'm just wondering, why you think that the query is little slow. How many `scan count` you get after run query?

Comment: I don't see scan count.  I have things like, Sort Cost 32%; Nested Loops Cost 1%; RID Lookup (Heap) Cost 58%; Index seek (NonClustered) 9%.  And thats about it, very clean as I said (everything else is at 0.

Comment: Run `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` before execution your original query and query from my answer. Also I see that you don't nave a clustered index. I right?